# AdMob - Banner não aparece no meu app

Tags: admob

Bom dia,

estou tentando incluir um banner em um aplicativo via AdMob seguindo o que consta em: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=pt-BR#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk

O problema começa quando tento inserir a linha abaixo nas dependências do meu gradle. O aplicativo dá erro e para a execução. OBS.: Por sugestões de amigos troquei a versão para a seguinte (implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'), com essa alteração o aplicativo rodou, porém o banner ainda não foi exibido.

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'

Abaixo as inserções que fiz:

**gradle(app)**

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.rtoshiro.mflibrary:mflibrary:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
AdView mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonCalcular"
            ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Quando estou no modo design da minha activity_main.xml o local do banner aparece, porém, ao rodar o app o banner não é exibido nem com os códigos fornecidos pela AdMob para testes.

Estou rodando direto no meu celular para os testes.

Comment: Se vc criou o banner a pouco, espere mais algumas horas que ele deve aparecer. Demora algum tempo até o banner começar a ser exibido.

Comment: Marceloawq, eu criei já tem 2 dias, e mesmo se eu setar o banner de teste fornecido pela AdMob não é exibido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido! O app estava encerrando devido um erro simples que eu não havia percebido no meu arquivo de Manifesto. A forma que estava dando problema e a forma que funcionou podem ser visualizadas abaixo:

Forma Errada:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="[ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713]"/>
```

Forma Correta:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
```

Abraços!