# Banner AdMob com problemas de exibição

Tags: java, android-studio, admob

Desenvolvi um aplicativo para Android em Java e adicionei um banner nele para exibição de anúncios. No modo de teste ele é exibido, mas quando coloco o código do banner do AdMob ele não apresenta o banner na tela, mas o contador de solicitações no AdMob vai aumentando.

Eu fiz toda a implementação do código com os manuais do AdMob.

Usando o [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=pt-BR#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk) para instanciar os anúncios.

[Banner Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=pt-BR) para colocar um banner na aplicação.

Minha conta no AdMob já tem mais de duas semanas, eu já tive alguns anúncios exibidos, mas agora não mais. Minha conta também não está bloqueada.

Os códigos estão da seguinte forma:

## build.Grade (Module:app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

## AndroidManifest.XML

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-7206755174693920~2499609222" />
```

## Activity_main.XML

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        ads:adSize= "BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

## MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AdView mAdView;
    AdRequest adRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Eu vi algumas pessoas com um problema parecido. [Nesse caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/338847/admob-banner-n%c3%a3o-aparece-no-meu-app), a pessoa tinha escrito o meta-data errado. Nesse mesma pergunta a implementação da `MainActivity.java` estava diferente da minha, eu deixei a minha igual, mas mesmo assim não obtive sucesso.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido.

Acontece que o AdMob mudou suas politicas de exibição de anúncios e a revisão do app pode demorar de dois até quinze dias, nesse tempo você não irá conseguir exibir nenhum anúncio.